# RemoteFileInfo Fails with Using statement

Tags: c#, using

I am having a problem with a pretty simply program.  We started off with this bit of working code:

```
RemoteFileInfo result = new RemoteFileInfo();

string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OmnitureSPDir"], request.FileName);
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);

// check if exists
if (!fileInfo.Exists)
    throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("File not found",
                      request.FileName);

// open stream
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath,
          System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

// return result 
result.FileName = request.FileName;
result.Length = fileInfo.Length;
result.FileByteStream = stream;

return result;
```

This takes in a parameter called "request" that contains the filename, we check to see if the file exists, and if so, we stream the file.

Well, after going through the microsoft code analysis in Visual Studio, and noticing that there was no dispose(), I "solved" the issue by wrapping it in a using statement:

```
using (RemoteFileInfo result = new RemoteFileInfo()) {

    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OmnitureSPDir"], request.FileName);
    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);

    // check if exists
    if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("File not found",
                          request.FileName);

    // open stream
    System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath,
              System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

    // return result 
    result.FileName = request.FileName;
    result.Length = fileInfo.Length;
    result.FileByteStream = stream;

    return result;
}
```

After running this code, we found that the file no longer would stream, but would error with:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: FileByteStream
```

Taking the Using() statement out, fixed the problem, but I don't understand why.  I thought I was doing a good thing, by adding in the code.  I would like to understand what I did wrong, so that I don't repeat it and can properly code this method.

Here is the definition for RemoteFileInfo

```
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && FileByteStream != null)
            {
                FileByteStream.Close();
                FileByteStream = null;
            }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but the `FileStream` also needs to be in a `using` block. Also, what is the 'RemoteFileInfo' class?

Comment: I updated the question with the definition of RemoteFileInfo, sorry that I didn't include that before.  I just realized that I had edited this file as well, to write the dispose object, perhaps my mistake was in there.

Comment: Are you returning an instance of `RemoteFileInfo` from a service?

Comment: Yes, we do.  My code above was missing the return statement (just added it), we return `return result;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning an object that implements `IDisposable`, then you cannot `Dispose` it. That has to be up to the caller.

Comment: Are you referring to my implementation of RemoteFileInfo class? that has Dispose()?  If so, I'm confused, because the code requires that I implement a dispose, it won't compile without it

Comment: It won't compile without it because you have it in a `using` block. You need to get rid of the `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

you have to Call Flush method in your stream it will correct the problem. It is because you make a dispose before flushing your stream so no data ;-)

Comment: I added in a call to `stream.Flush()` before the return, but that didn't help.  I don't think it would help, because we need to return the stream, not the entire data all at once.